# Adding parent div over multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to add a parent div.

```
<div id="faceone"><img src=""></div>

<div id="facetwo" ><img src=""></div>

<div id="facethree"><img src=""></div

<div id="facefour"><img src=""></div>
```

These are four divs and i want to add a parent div above them. I tried this

```
$('#faceone').wrapAll('<div class="cubeSpinner">');
```

But this is adding cubeSpinner above faceone only

```
<div class="cubeSpinner">

<div id="faceone"><img src=""></div>

</div>
<div id="facetwo" ><img src=""></div>

<div id="facethree"><img src=""></div

<div id="facefour"><img src=""></div>
```

But i want the result should be like this

```
<div class="cubeSpinner">

<div id="faceone"><img src=""></div>

<div id="facetwo" ><img src=""></div>

<div id="facethree"><img src=""></div

<div id="facefour"><img src=""></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to select all the elements in order for them to be wrapped. I'd suggest adding a common class to them, but in the meantime you could use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[id^="face"]` to select all elements with an `id` attribute that begins with 'face':

```
$('[id^="face"]').wrapAll('<div class="cubeSpinner"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've shown this example on JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/azu2s4r9/

You should use the .wrapAll() jquery function for this and add a common class name to each of the four existing `<div>` tags.  Your new original code will look like this.

```
<div id="faceone" class="test"><img src=""></div>
<div id="facetwo" class="test"><img src=""></div>
<div id="facethree" class="test"><img src=""></div>
<div id="facefour" class="test"><img src=""></div>
```

Then your jquery code should look like this.

```
$('.test').wrapAll('<div class="cubeSpinner">Testing</div>');
```

The resulting code will look like this which is how you wanted it to finish.

```
<div class="cubeSpinner">Testing
<div id="faceone" class="test"><img src=""></div>
<div id="facetwo" class="test"><img src=""></div>
<div id="facethree" class="test"><img src=""><div>
<div id="facefour" class="test"><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

This provides a complete solution and should work in pretty much all cases.  Good luck!